# how to do match a word in a line in perl and remove it and using them separately?

Tags: perl

for example in one perl file it is like this:

```
123 abc xyz
456 abc sdf
789 abc ghj
```

Now from above lines I need to separate remove `abc` and assign

```
value 1=123
value 2= xyz
value 3= 456
value 4= sdf
```

Help me how to code for above requirement.

Comment: Hello Sruthi, did you try something on your own? It will be great, if you can show us *what you tried* and *what problems are you facing*. Meanwhile, you should also check [`How to ask`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish? Can you show us your code to give us an idea of what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $count = 0;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  for (split / abc /) {
    $count++;
    say "value $count=", ($count == 1 ? '' : ' '), $_;
  }
}

__DATA__
123 abc xyz
456 abc sdf
789 abc ghj
```

Or, perhaps a more data-driven approach to determining which rows omit the space after the `=`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %nospace = (
  1 => 1,
);

my $count = 0;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  for (split / abc /) {
    $count++;
    say "value $count=", ($nospace{$count} ? '' : ' '), $_;
  }
}

__DATA__
123 abc xyz
456 abc sdf
789 abc ghj
```